# CSS: How to make an element stay in the same place when scrollitn and not scroll down with the page?

Tags: html, css

The problem is that I'm trying to create an arrow in the bottom center of the screen that is bouncing all the time. And when clicking it getting a scroll down to a certain point. I have the script for the scrolling and that is solved the problem is that when I type position:fixed the arrow scrolls down with the page but when I write position:absolute the element sticks to the left and margins aren't working, what should I do?

This is my code:

(HTML)

```
<div class="arrow bounce">
<a class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-2x" href="#About"></a>
</div>
```

(CSS)

```
@bg: #fff; // White
@primary: #fff; // White

body { background: @bg;}
a { color: white; text-decoration: none; }

.arrow {
text-align: center;
margin: 8% 0;


}
.bounce {
-moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
-webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

.arrow, .bounce{
position:fixed;
left: 50%;
bottom: 20px;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
margin: 0 auto
}
@keyframes bounce {
0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
transform: translateY(0);
}
40% {
transform: translateY(-30px);
}
60% {
transform: translateY(-15px);
 }
}
```

Comment: The animation on `.bounce` is removing the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` that is keeping it in the middle.

Comment: So should I remove  and change the position to absolute?

Comment: See if you can add multiple `translate` values to the `transform`. I'm not sure if you can, but I think that would be better.

Comment: I can't do that... Do you have any other solution?

Comment: So change the position to absolute and change the animation to using `bottom` instead of `transform`.